# Can  jalapeños be grown from pickled jalapeño seeds?

Tags: chili, seeds, germination, jalapenos

I bought a bottle of pickled jalapeno today, and I see there are seeds inside them.

It is hard for my local area to acquire jalapeno seeds, so I am wondering if it is possible to grow jalapenos from these seeds in the pickled jalapenos.

The juice is made with water, salt and acidity regulator.

Comment: One woman tried it and she had great results here's the link >> http://forums2.gardenweb.com/forums/load/seed/msg1200053924394.html I'm trying it myself. :) Good luck!

Comment: Can you buy them online and have them shipped to you? What's your country? Does a mail service go to your area? My concern with planting the pickled seeds, whether or not they would be viable, is that it may be a legally restricted kind of pepper (in the USA and maybe certain other countries, at least). If they're refrigerator pickles, they might germinate. If they've been canned, I have my doubts, but you can always try it. Miracles happen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely no.

The pickling process typically boils the bottles to a point that kills any organisms in order to prevent spoilage -- this includes the seeds.

(I say "most likely" because some pickling processes are done cold and use a more natural sort of fermentation. But unless you got your pickled peppers at a very traditional sort of shop or from an old-school farmer at a farmers' market, they've been boiled and the seeds will not grow.)

Beyond the processing issue, even if the seeds were viable, if your peppers happen to be a hybrid variety, you won't get plants that produce the same fruit.

Considering that you can get 100 viable jalapeno seeds for under US$2, it's really not worth bothering trying to salvage the debris off the bottom of the pickle jar...

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @bstpierre: almost certainly no. Even if they were produced using a process that didn't heat treat them, and they survived the brine, then there's still a very low chance. I am basing this on my observation that most seeds from fresh store-bought peppers do not grow - even though they haven't been heat treated and they are young. Which is another factor: how long have your peppers sat in that jar?

(Edit) It sounds like your underlying problem is that you are trying to obtain jalapeno seeds. Big box sellers and grocers often have them. So might the big box garden stores - although healthy plants might be the better choice (which it sounds like they don't have). There are a number of specialist mail order pepper suppliers. You don't say where you are, but for the US, I've used [Pepper Gal](http://www.peppergal.com/) for the past 5+ years now. No complaints - just a happy customer. They have lots of seed varieties (I haven't counted but must be over a hundred peppers), so not only can you choose "jalapeno" but you can also choose the 'heat', colour and climate to match your requirements.

Comment: OP's profile says Hong Kong. That's likely to be a challenge - I don't know if you're allowed to mail-order seeds across international borders.

Comment: It will depend on the jurisdictions, but you often can. Most controls (eg. of fruit) are for parasites/pests - not a problem for the actual seeds. The main concerns are invasives (little legislation in place) and CITES (generally legislated for by most countries).

Answer (score 2):

Some of the pickled jalapenos seeds are alrady germinating in the jar, you probably just didn't notice it. Put them on wet cotton and see what happens. Thank me later. Try. Experiment. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The seeds are rugged and survive the digestive acids of animals.  Chilli plants will grow from pickled jars no problems